# Elasticsearch Index template lost raw string mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm running a small ELK 5.4.0 stack server on a single node.  When I started, I just took all the defaults, which meant 5 shards for each index.  I didn't want the overhead of all those shards, so I created an index template like so:

```
PUT /_template/logstash
{
  "template": "logstash*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
```

This worked fine, but I just realized that all my raw fields are now missing in ES.  For example, "uri" is one of my indexed fields and I used to get "uri.raw" as an unanalyzed version of it.  But since I updated the template, they are missing.  Looking at the current template shows

```
GET /_template/logstash
Returns:
{
    "logstash": {
        "order": 0,
        "template": "logstash*",
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "0"
            }
        },
        "mappings": {},
        "aliases": {}
    }
}
```

It seems that the mappings have gone missing.  I can pull the mappings off an earlier index

```
GET /logstash-2017.03.01
```

and compare it with a recent one

```
GET /logstash-2017.08.01
```

Here I see that back in March there was a mapping structure like

```
mappings: {
    "logs": {
        "_all": {...},
        "dynamic_templates": {...},
        "properties": {...}
    },
    "_default_": {
        "_all": {...},
        "dynamic_templates": {...},
        "properties": {...}
    }
}
```

and now I have only

```
mappings: {
    "logs": {
        "properties": {...}
    }
}
```

The dynamic_templates hash holds the information about creating "raw" fields.

My guess is that I need to add to update my index template to

```
PUT /_template/logstash
{
  "template": "logstash*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "logs": {
        "_all": {...},
        "dynamic_templates": {...},
    },
    "_default_": {
        "_all": {...},
        "dynamic_templates": {...},
        "properties": {...}
    }
}
```

IOW, everything but `logs.properties` (which holds the current list of fields being sent over by logstash).

But I'm not an ES expert and now I'm a bit worried.  My original index template didn't work out the way I thought it would.  Is my above plan going to work?  Or am I going to make things worse?  Must you always include *everything* when you create an index template?  And where did the mappings for the older indexes, before I had a template file, come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Logstash first starts, the `elasticsearch` output plugin installs [its own index template](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template-es5x.json) with the `_default_` template and `dynamic_templates` as you correctly figured out.

Everytime Logstash creates a new `logstash-*` index (i.e. every day), the template is leveraged and the index is created with the proper mapping(s) present in the template.

What you need to do now is simply to take the official logstash template that you have overridden and reinstall it like this (but with the modified shard settings):

```
PUT /_template/logstash
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "version" : 50001,
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
    "index.number_of_shards": 1,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "norms" : false},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "path_match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "norms" : false
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text", "norms" : false,
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 }
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "include_in_all": false },
        "@version": { "type": "keyword", "include_in_all": false },
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "half_float" },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "half_float" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another way you could have done it is to not overwrite the `logstash` template, but use any other id, such as `_template/my_logstash`, so that at index creation time, both templates would have kicked in and used the mappings from the official logstash template and the shard settings from your template.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!  One note to add in case it's not clear: the ".raw" fields have now been changed to ".keyword" field.  But everything is working as you predicted!